# Recent technical documentation for boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm looking for up-to-date technical documentation for Boost.Asio library.

I've explored the official Boost.Asio website, but it doesn't provide in-depth technical documentation. I'm interested in delving deeper into the internal implementation.

Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the latest features, improvements, and usage guidelines.

Could someone please provide me with links or references to recent documentation sources or guides that cover the internal implementation and usage of Boost.Asio?

Any insights, examples, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you look exactly? [Here](https://think-async.com/Asio/Documentation.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Nelfeal, this is great, thank you ! – [Peter 1 hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526048/recent-technical-documentation-for-boost-asio#comment134928860_76526048)

To wit, the [Think-Async documentation](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.28.0/doc/) is [identical to the Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), but `think-async.com` used to have relevant blog posts.

I think ironically, the blog posts sort-of dried up a little, but the Asio docs (mirrored in Boost) have [grown *tremendously* over recent releases](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html), and I'm starting to consider them in-depth.

This is in stark contrast with, say, 4 or 5 years ago, when I felt the best documentation of Asio principles and mechanisms were found in Beast (e.g. [this article](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html) used the be the only *comprehensible* documentation, whereas recent Asio documentation contains a wealth of different conceptual documentation of [async result, completion token](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html) and [composition](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition.html) as well as [examples with *very rich* inline explanations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp20_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp20_examples.operations).

I think the [C++ Alliance](https://cppalliance.org/) has played a great role as catalyst to generate this trend to deeper documentation.

> *In that context, I just remembered that Klemens Morgenstern sat down with Chris Kohlhoff to talk about basic concepts in YouTube videos, and they were exceptionally grounded.* See here e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icgnqFM-aY4